# Adicionar and e or em Where() de lista

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lista, where

Tenho uma lista em `C#` e atualmente o código de busca está assim:

```
filter = lst.Where(s => s.Contains(num.Text) ).Take(3).ToList();
```

A lista `lst` se baseia em uma lista com números de telefones e nomes de contatos, exemplo:

```
123456789$nome1

987654321$nome2
```

Atualmente estou buscando pelo número, queria fazer um OR para poder buscar tambem pelo nome exemplo:

```
num.Text = 9;
nome.Text = "l";
```

Queria pegar os 3 primeiros itens da lista que tem o valor de `nome.Text` OU de `num.Text`

Comment: Alguma dificuldade específica? É igual a um ´if`` .

Comment: A `lst` possui campos do tipo Numérico ou Texto?

Comment: Tem muito tempo que não mexo com C#, hoje fui adicionar essa funcionalidade e não lembro de nada do método `Where`, a condição dele seria se `s` contem `num.Tex`t ou `nome.Text`

Comment: lst é uma lista de `string`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use o operador or `||` dentro de seu where.

```
filter = lst.Where(s => s.Contains(num.Text) || s.Contains(nome.Text) ).Take(3).ToList();
```

Eis um exemplo que fiz no DotNet Fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/EYC2gF

Answer (score 4):

Pode fazer igual a um `if`:

```
filter = lst.Where(s => s.Contains(num.Text) || s.Contains(nome.Text)).Take(3).ToList();
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/CBALDx). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jHQf3k). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/FilterText.cs).

Isso fará para todos os itens da lista. Item por item, um de cada vez. Primeiro procurá por um critério, se achar, ótimo, se não achar, ele faz a busca no segundo critério, se achar ele retornará `true` e avançará pra o `Take(3)`. Quando ele chegar no terceiro item que deu `true` ele não procurá mais nada. E esta é uma das belezas do LINQ, ele não perde tempo com o que não precisa mais (ajudado neste caso pelo mecanismo de *short-circuit* dos operadores relacionais.

Eventualmente pode ser feita otimizações, mas duvido que seja necessário na maioria dos casos